# Prefabs don't appear anymore after open project

Tags: unity-game-engine

My game prefabs (blood on the wall) don't appear anymore after I open the project. Instead, a grey plane appears. What can I do to make them show again?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the texture of the material is missing.

The inspector setting for the original material should be like this:
[image]

---

Click the **Select** button to set the texture. And make sure the shader is correct.

[image]
[image]